# Me marca un error de permisos en IIS

Tags: .net, iis

Estaba trabajando de manera normal y apague la computadora se instalaron las tipicas actualizaciones y ahora cuando quiero abrir la solucion me marca

```
El proyecto de aplicación web SiteServer está configurado para usar IIS.
No se puede obtener acceso a la metabase de IIS. 
No tiene privilegios suficientes para obtener acceso a los sitios web de IIS en su equipo.
```

Esto en un proyecto de visual con el framework 4.0

No se cual sea el origen del error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Me he encontrado con el mismo problema y la solución ha sido esta:

> - Abrir el archivo .csproj del proyecto y cambiar la siguiente línea:
>     `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` a `<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>`
> - Guardar el archivo.
> - Recargar tu proyecto.

Solución encontrada aquí: https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/a628cd

Sé que la pregunta es antigua, pero por si alguien llega aquí con una búsqueda como la mía.